# VS Code Showing 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a maven project with VS Code but when I run the command it says :

> `'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

but `mvn -version` is running on command prompt

Environment varaible for User :

`MAVEN_JOME : C:\apache-maven-3.6.1`,
`M2_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.6.1`,
`JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\jre` and

System Variables

`path` is set to `C:\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin`, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin` for maven and java respectively.

The command  I'm running to create the project is: 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.cs.test-project -DartifactId=test-project -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false` [The Reference to Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671308/how-to-create-a-java-maven-project-that-works-in-visual-studio-code)

And the VS Code [Reference to Command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_generate-project-from-maven-archetype)

> The same command is running in Command prompt and it created the project successfully on Desktop.

Comment: mvn is not in the path known to visual studio code.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set

Comment: could you show the system environment varaible screenshot,if mvn -version is running,it means you have set the mvn path already,it's strange

Comment: I have set the maven path but still its not running I will attach the screenshot later

Comment: As per your statement: `MAVEN_JOME : C:\MAVEN\apache-maven-3.6.1`, `M2_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.6.1`, so my question is are these 2 different folders (C:\MAVEN\apache... & C:\apache....) ? or you have set path in one of them incorrectly?

Comment: Also, from command line, what is the output for 1. %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn and 2. %MAVEN_HOME%\bin\mvn ?

Comment: the `MAVEN_HOME :  C:\apache-maven-3.6.1` and  `M2_HOME : C:\apache-maven-3.6.1` both are same that was a typing mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.I'm correcting in the question also.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved ?

Comment: Just in case this helps someone. I had something similar. I solved it by simply restarting the VS Code. (Just as one needs to start a new CMD in order to recognize a change in environment variables)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem by simply restarting VSCode as I had set my PATH variable while my VSCode was running so the changes were not reflected to the VSCode integrated terminal until I restarted it.

Answer (score 4):

It's kindy counterintuitive as path has to be pointed to the actual mvn command, instead to a M2_PATH folder. Also once properly pointed, a new error will be shown if your environment is missing proper jdk within JAVA_HOME. The error is trown by maven. Maven plugin is kinda stupid as it will ignore your default JDK configured within settings.json (java.home or/and java.configuration.runtimes properties) and will happly NOT set java for maven. You have to configure it specificly for maven plugin as this:

```
"maven.executable.path": "c:\\apache-maven-3.8.1\\bin\\mvn",
"maven.terminal.customEnv": [{
        "environmentVariable": "JAVA_HOME",                
        "value": "c:\\openjdk-1.8.0_232-redhat",
}]
```

Of course, both paths should be pointed to proper folders/files in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

On Tuesday Oct. 25, 2022 while trying to solve the same problem, I went through all of these previous solutions for Windows and finally had to resort to the official installation docs:

[Installing Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Unzipped the [download](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and located the bin directory and manually added that directory location to my: System Properties>Advanced>Environment Variables>'Path'

For good measure, restart the computer.

Comment: You need to do this for Ubuntu as well because Ubuntu's package on Ubuntu 20.0 is so much outdated, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed was by changing the exec path in Vs Code settings from CMD to Powershell.

Open

```
settings -> features -> terminal
```

Change the `windows exec` path from cmd to where you have PowerShell.

For example: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

[Windows exec setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5rYy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.0.

In my case, I added the path to the Maven binary directory manually to the `$PATH` variable. I accidentally only added it to the environment variables in the shell but not to the user session.

Also make sure you are using the official binary that you can download from Maven's website and not the Ubuntu APT package because that one is too old and did not work for me.

Let's assume, the Maven executable has been stored in `~/apache-maven/bin`. Then you can edit `~/.profile` by adding `export PATH+=":$HOME/apache-maven/bin"`.

Restart the computer and then, when you login to your profile, `mvn` should be visible by programs as well as VSCode.