# Kotlin VSCode extension unable to find the 'mvn' command

Tags: kotlin, gradle, visual-studio-code, gradlew

But in a terminal I can see a Maven version:

```
11:58 $ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /home/stephane/.asdf/installs/maven/3.8.4
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /home/stephane/.asdf/installs/java/adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-91-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I'm using the [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) tool:

```
12:07 $ cat .tool-versions 
java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
nodejs 12.13.1
tflint 0.28.1
terraform-validator 3.1.3
packer 1.7.2
terraform 0.15.3
adr-tools 3.0.0
pre-commit 1.21.0
maven 3.8.4
```

When loading the project the bottom Output pane for the Kotlin console shows the content:

```
Dec 18, 2021 12:06:26 PM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint fallbackResponseError
SEVERE: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the 'mvn' command
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the 'mvn' command
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the 'mvn' command
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt$mvnCommand$2.invoke(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:129)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt$mvnCommand$2.invoke(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:128)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.getMvnCommand(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:128)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.generateMavenDependencyList(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:106)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.access$generateMavenDependencyList(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:1)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolver.getClasspathWithSources(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:37)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.UnionClassPathResolver.<init>(ClassPathResolver.kt:57)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.ClassPathResolverKt.plus(ClassPathResolver.kt:45)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.ClassPathResolverKt.getJoined(ClassPathResolver.kt:40)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.DefaultClassPathResolverKt.defaultClassPathResolver(DefaultClassPathResolver.kt:11)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.refresh(CompilerClassPath.kt:37)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.refresh$default(CompilerClassPath.kt:31)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.addWorkspaceRoot(CompilerClassPath.kt:98)
    at org.javacs.kt.KotlinLanguageServer$initialize$1.invoke(KotlinLanguageServer.kt:117)
    at org.javacs.kt.KotlinLanguageServer$initialize$1.invoke(KotlinLanguageServer.kt:71)
    at org.javacs.kt.util.AsyncExecutor.compute$lambda-2(AsyncExecutor.kt:19)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more

[Error - 11:51:28 AM] Starting client failed
  Message: Internal error.
  Code: -32603 
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the 'mvn' command
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find the 'mvn' command
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt$mvnCommand$2.invoke(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:129)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt$mvnCommand$2.invoke(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:128)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.getMvnCommand(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:128)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.generateMavenDependencyList(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:106)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolverKt.access$generateMavenDependencyList(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:1)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.MavenClassPathResolver.getClasspathWithSources(MavenClassPathResolver.kt:37)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.UnionClassPathResolver.<init>(ClassPathResolver.kt:57)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.ClassPathResolverKt.plus(ClassPathResolver.kt:45)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.ClassPathResolverKt.getJoined(ClassPathResolver.kt:40)
    at org.javacs.kt.classpath.DefaultClassPathResolverKt.defaultClassPathResolver(DefaultClassPathResolver.kt:11)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.refresh(CompilerClassPath.kt:37)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.refresh$default(CompilerClassPath.kt:31)
    at org.javacs.kt.CompilerClassPath.addWorkspaceRoot(CompilerClassPath.kt:98)
    at org.javacs.kt.KotlinLanguageServer$initialize$1.invoke(KotlinLanguageServer.kt:117)
    at org.javacs.kt.KotlinLanguageServer$initialize$1.invoke(KotlinLanguageServer.kt:71)
    at org.javacs.kt.util.AsyncExecutor.compute$lambda-2(AsyncExecutor.kt:19)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    ... 3 more
```

The extension log shows:

```
[2021-12-18 11:51:28.974] [exthost] [error] Activating extension fwcd.kotlin failed due to an error:
[2021-12-18 11:51:28.975] [exthost] [error] Error: Internal error.
    at /home/stephane/.vscode/extensions/fwcd.kotlin-0.2.23/dist/extension.js:2:815204
    at /home/stephane/.vscode/extensions/fwcd.kotlin-0.2.23/dist/extension.js:2:815498
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/stephane/.vscode/extensions/fwcd.kotlin-0.2.23/dist/extension.js:2:815863)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

It is a Gradle main project with a `build.xml` file in the project root directory, with Gradle sub projects and Maven sub projects.

There are many `build.xml` `pom.xml` `gradlew` `gradlew.bat` files in the sub projects.

Releases:

```
VSCode 1.63.2
Extensions:
Language Support for Java v1.2.0
Kotlin v0.2.23
```

Comment: where you able overcome this issue?

Comment: No, I had to switch to IntelliJ and I now no longer work in this outfit.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.0, I had the same issue which was caused by my Maven installation. `mvn` ran in the VSCode terminal but was not found by the extension.

I also tried another Stack Overflow answer:
[set maven extension settings in the user's settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73006994/12316388)
But this one is only for the commands that you can trigger in the "Maven" subsection inside the "Explorer" (the file view of VSCode).

For Ubuntu, Maven needs to be downloaded manually from the website because the Ubuntu APT package is too old.

My error was to edit the PATH variable in the `.bashrc` script which only is visible in shell environments. It seems the extension does not run commands in a shell environment.

When you have installed Maven for all users on Ubuntu, you can edit the PATH variable inside `/etc/environment`. If it is only installed locally – in my case it is located inside `~/apache-maven/bin` – you could add the directory to the PATH variable inside `~/.profile` (or `~/.pam_environment` respectively), by adding maven's directory path – in my case `$HOME/apache-maven/bin` – to the PATH. This worked for me.