# Can't create Maven project in VScode: "Program 'cmd' failed to run"

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I've been trying for so long to get Maven for Java to work in VS code but every time I try making a new project I get this error:

```
Program 'cmd' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ cmd /c mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd /c mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="maven-archetype- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I have both the Java sdk and ApacheMaven installed (mvn -v works in cmd) but I keep getting this error in VScode!

Comment: Might be easier to report this as an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) to the vscode team

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the question? How are you running that command?

Comment: @Golu I'm not running any commands myself, I'm trying to create a new Maven project through the VSCode GUI (there's a button that adds a new project) and I keep getting that error. I've tried multiple Maven archetypes and they all give that same error, every single time.

Comment: you could refer to the [create maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727175/10768653)

Comment: could it work follow the link step ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the VSCode as an administrator.It should work fine then.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't fix it, I got the same error as before :-/