# VScode java project build and run from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have java project generated in Visual Studio Code (installed addon: [Java Extension Pack](http://java%20-jar%20/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar%20-noSplash%20-data%20%22workspace%22%20-application%20org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild) )

Everything works properly when i work with it using IDE, but i would like to know how to build and run it using only commandline.

I would also like to generate .jar file from my project but I can't find such an option.

Files generated by this project:

`.classpath`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

`.project`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<projectDescription>
  <name>java_project</name>
  <comment/>
  <projects>
    </projects>
  <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
      <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
      <arguments>
            </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
  </buildSpec>
  <natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: In VS Code the most common way for that is to use Maven (the Java Extension Pack is a headless Eclipse via LSP, without the dialogs and wizards of the Eclipse IDE).

Comment: you could build with maven,and do it in command line,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727175/10768653