# How to let VS Code know the path to Non-JDK Classes?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation, search-path

My Java program imports a non JDK class downloaded and placed in the same directory as my Java file. How do I let VS Code know the path to this class so I don't get the red under squiggle for class not resolved error?

Currently when I compile I need to `java -cp /path/to/Non-JDK/class.jar MyClass.java` is there a way to add `/path/to/Non-JDK/class.jar` to the search path of the compiler so I can just `java MyClass.java`?

Comment: If you have non JDK dependencies you should use maven to manage them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671308/how-to-create-a-java-maven-project-that-works-in-visual-studio-code#:~:text=Open%20the%20Maven%20project%20folder,Executes%20common%20Maven%20commands%22).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can click Add icon under `JAVA PROJECTS` -> `Referenced Libraries`, it will modify `"java.project.referencedLibraries"` in the settings.json file automatically, or you can modify it directly.