VSCode doesn't see the Java Project as Java Project
I'm newbie in Java world, but I know some concepts and want to practice in Java.
My environment:
> echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

> java --version
java 17.0.10 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)

ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 Apr 29 10:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Mar  1 14:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Apr 29 10:57 jdk-17.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Mar  1 14:12 jdk-21.jdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   45 Mar  1 18:03 openjdk-11.jdk -> /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk

Steps I did:
I built a project based on flink guidance using maven:
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.flink \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=flink-walkthrough-datastream-java \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.18.1 \
    -DgroupId=com.test.project \
    -DartifactId=test-project \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -Dpackage=com.test.project \
    -DinteractiveMode=false

When I opened this project in VSCode and tried to run the class, I see the following error:
Error: Main method not found in the file, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

I tried to setup .vscode/settings.json with following values:
{
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-17",
      "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}

VSCode user settings look like:
"maven.executable.path": "/Users/vladislav/dependencies/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin/mvn",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home",
            "default": true
        },
    ],
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home",

The project contains the file FraudDetectionJob.java with the main function:
package com.test.project;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.sink.AlertSink;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Alert;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.source.TransactionSource;

/**
 * Skeleton code for the datastream walkthrough
 */
public class FraudDetectionJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}


Also I tried to create the project not via Maven CLI, but via Maven extension -> result is the same.

Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671308/how-to-create-a-java-maven-project-that-works-in-visual-studio-code

Unfortunately, didn't help

If possible import https://github.com/jabedhasan21/java-hello-world-with-maven sample maven java app and run the main class and see what happens
